# How to get all the defects in Quality Center 11 by Restful API

Tags: hp-quality-center

I use `https://qcxxx.xxx.com:443/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/defects` but I can only get 100 defects. Actually there are many more than 100 defects. Why is this?

Comment: What does the API documentation say?

Comment: That just repeats your question. What does the API doc say? I would guess by default it only returns 100, so there is presumably a way of telling it either to return more, or to return the next 100.

Comment: If that has solved your problem, please make that an answer, and accept it. Otherwise, this question will keep popping up as an open QTP question, getting attention from thousands of QTP users for years. And -- for nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass some paramethers to "fix" it.

/defects?page-size=X&start-index=Y

X is the number of how many defects you can see at same page.
Y is the number of how many defects you will "skip".

There are some limits that are setted in QC configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

`/defects?page-size=max`

This also has a limited amount of returns, but is a simple way of getting all of the results, as long as it doesn't exceed the set max page size. I don't remember the default max page size right now, but it is a few thousands. I also know it can be changed according to your needs, in settings. I've set mine to 5000.

**UPDATE:**
from the API:

> If the specified page-size is greater than the maximum page size, an
>   exception is thrown. The maximum page size can be specified by the
>   site parameter REST_API_MAX_PAGE_SIZE. If the site parameter is not
>   defined, the maximum page size is 2000. The requested page size can be
>   set equal to the maximum by specifying page-size=max.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a c# function we used that returns the ids of all our hp alm/qc defects having attachments and using pagination in the rest api url.

```cs
public List<string> GetDefectIds()
{
    XmlNodeList nodeIds = null;
    int iteration = 0;
    List<string> returnIds = new List<string>();
    do
    {
        string queryString = "?fields=id&query={attachment['Y']}&page-size=" + Constant.ALM_DEFECTS_PAGE_SIZE.ToString() + "&start-index=" + (iteration++ * Constant.ALM_DEFECTS_PAGE_SIZE + 1).ToString();
        string url = _urlBase + "/rest/domains/" + _domain + "/projects/" + _project + "/defects" + queryString;
        WebRequest wrq = WebRequest.Create(url);
        wrq.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, _sessionCookie);
        WebResponse wrp = wrq.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(wrp.GetResponseStream());
        string xmlString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlString);
        nodeIds = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Entities/Entity/Fields/Field/Value");
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeIds)
        {
            returnIds.Add(node.InnerXml);
        }
        wrp.Close();
    }
    while (nodeIds?.Count > 0);
    return returnIds;
}
```

Variables starting with underscore are private class members and the alm page size constant is equal to 250.